# How to change background color in quicker way?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a painting program where one can draw things, change the background color and save it as a file on the computer. Everything works except that changing the background color takes way too much time.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as tk
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile,askopenfilename
import os
from PIL import Image as im
from PIL import ImageTk,ImageDraw,ImageColor


class P:
    x=y=None
    image=None

    my_image=im.new("RGB",(600,600),(255,255,255))
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.upper_frame = Frame(window)
        self.upper_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=5,sticky="ew")
        self.lower_frame = Frame(window)
        self.lower_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5,sticky="ew")
        self.canvas= Canvas(self.lower_frame,width=700,height=530,bg="white")
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.bg = Button(self.upper_frame,text="Background",command= self.bgcolor) #change bg color
        self.bg.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=(100,10))
        self.upper_menu()

    def bgcolor(self):
            chosen_color = askcolor(color=self.canvas["bg"])[1]
            self.canvas.configure(bg=chosen_color)
            color_RGB = ImageColor.getcolor(chosen_color, "RGB")
            img = self.my_image
            for i in range(0,600):#pixels in width
                for j in range(0,600): #height = 600 pix
                    data = img.getpixel((i,j)) #gives color of pixel
                    if (data[0]==255 and data[1]==255 and data[2]==255): #data represent RGB color
                        img.putpixel((i,j),color_RGB) #changes pixel color
    
    def save_pic(self,event=None): #save image on comp.
        my_file=asksaveasfile(mode="w",defaultextension=".png",filetypes=[("png files","*.png")],
                              initialdir="/home/b/",parent=window)
        
        if my_file is not None:
            path=os.path.abspath(my_file.name)
            self.my_image.save(path)
            
    def upper_menu(self):
        self.menubar = Menu(window)
        self.menu1 = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu1.add_command(label="Save pic", command=self.save_pic)
        self.menu1.add_separator()
        self.menu1.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=self.menu1)
        self.menu2 = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.window.config(menu=self.menubar)
            
window = Tk()
window.geometry("720x590")
p = P(window)

window.mainloop()
```

I use the method *bgcolor* to change the background. How to make it work faster?

Comment: Woah that loop is _huge_

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with calling `putpixel` 360,000 times. Instead, try creating the color data in the loop and then call `putdata` once after the loops have finished.

I'm not overly familiar with PIL, but this makes a *huge* difference when doing similar things with the tkinter `PhotoImage` class: doing one pixel at a time is slow, doing an array of pixels is fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any example of how to do that? I tried searching for some examples but didn't find any.